# How to get the median of Z=f(x,y)?

Tags: probability, median

Defining $Z=f(x,y)$ in interval $[q,1][q,1]$,$x,y$ are all i.i.d. uniform.
I know that, if $f(x,y)$ is non-increasing or non-decreasing for both $x$ and $y$, the median of $z$ is $f((1-q)/2,(1-q)/2)$. But if $f(x,y)$ is non-increasing or non-decreasing for only $x$, and it is not non-increasing or non-decreasing for $y$.

How can I get the median of $Z$?

The figure of $Z$ is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Monte Carlo solution coded in [R](http://www.r-project.org).

```
N <- 10^6
f <- function(x, y) x^2 + y^2 # or whatever
x <- runif(N)
y <- runif(N)
median(f(x, y))
```

Comment: thank you very much!I know this method, but I want to get the expression of the median of $Z$.just like the one-dimension. Do you know how to express the median of $Z$?

Comment: $Z$ is one-dimensional. The median of Z is a real number $m$ such that $P(Z\leq m)=F_Z(m)=1/2$. Hence, if you want an analytic expression for $m$, the first step is to compute $F_Z$, the distribution function of $Z$, and then work with it. In general, there will be no closed form for $m$.